# How to shave off image in Java?

Tags: java, image

This is what I need to do. I need to create square thumbnails from a standard photo. The photos are usually portrain layout, so I need to shave off the bottom part of the photo so that the height is equals to the width.

If the image is landscape layout then I need to shave off equal number of pixels from left and right to make it square.

Any ideas how to do this?

My image is BufferedImage object already.

Comment: In portrait only shave off from bottom, in landscape shave off equal number from right and left. That's the rule I need to enforce. I've been doing this in my php project and it works well to generate square avatars from uploaded images. I just don't know how to do this in Java.

Comment: You did say that in your original post -- my bad. So I've deleted my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getSubimage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to retrieve a cropped version of the original image.